# TFTP error when downloading larger files

Tags: bash, shell, networking, embedded, tftp

Embedded Linux device, with BusyBox v1.4.2 multi-call binary.
I tried download files from remote device to local computer via TFTP, but got some issue: it works OK for small files (about ~350MB), but when I tried download bigger files, like mtdblock (about 3.5MB size), download fails.

Download starts, but downloads only about ~900KB, then falls. TFTP show timeout, and also `errors tftp: server says: 'Access violation' or 'Illegal TFTP operation'`.

```
tftp -l /dev/mtdblock3 -p 192.168.100.10

mtd blocks:

# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00020000 00010000 "U-Boot"
mtd1: 00010000 00010000 "env1"
mtd2: 00010000 00010000 "env2"
mtd3: 003a0000 00010000 "UBFI1"
mtd4: 003a0000 00010000 "UBFI2"
mtd5: 000cf6f4 00010000 "Kernel"
mtd6: 002cc800 00010000 "RootFileSystem"
mtd7: 00070000 00010000 "nvram"


# cd dev
# ls -l

brw-rw----    1 0        0         31,   3 mtdblock3
brw-rw----    1 0        0         31,   4 mtdblock4
...
crw-rw----    1 0        0         90,   6 mtd3
crw-rw----    1 0        0         90,   7 mtd3ro
crw-rw----    1 0        0         90,   8 mtd4
crw-rw----    1 0        0         90,   9 mtd4ro
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add to post the package your are using for TFTP.

Comment: Switch to binary mode?

Comment: The original protocol had file limitation. No idea about current implementations. However TFTP is not oriented to such workloads, only to serve small files to bootstrap operating systems. Usually SCP is a better choice.

Comment: @Cyrus tftp in Busybox in binary mode by default.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro Not sure about TFTP package, BusyBox v1.4.2 multi-call binary.  Precompiled code is running on embedded device, SCP is not available among currently defined BusyBox functions.

Comment: I don't think file size limit is the issue. The original protocol has a transfer file size limit of 512 bytes/block x 65535 blocks = 32 MB. In 1998 this limit was extended to 1468 bytes/block x 65535 blocks = 93 MB by TFTP Blocksize Option RFC 2348.